# Visual Studio - Menu Options - Float Right or Left

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I clicked on **something** in Visual Studio 2017 and now all the dropdown menu options are floating to the left instead of the default right. Below is a print screen of how it should look...

[image]

But I get something like this, floats to the left ...

[image]

I've gone through the options pretty thoroughly but I can't seem to find the option for this. Does anyone know where the option to control this is?

Comment: VS observes the OS setting, floating to the left tends to be the preference of right-handed users on a tablet PC.  We don't know your OS version, look here for example: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/68038-set-menus-open-aligned-left-right-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Brilliant, you should post this as an answer so I can give you some points. That would also explain why I could not find anything in VS 2017 to change this.

Answer (score 6):

The direction of the menus in Visual Studio is actually controlled by a setting on OS level. On recent versions of Windows, it's pretty well hidden but you can directly run the following in the `Windows -> Run dialog` (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) to open the settings dialog:

```
explorer shell:::{80F3F1D5-FECA-45F3-BC32-752C152E456E}
```

and change the radio button in `Tablet PC Settings -> Other -> Handedness` to `Right-handed`.

Comment: The "Other" tab is not there in Windows 11. :(

Comment: In Windows 10, at least, I can open a command prompt, cd to \Windows\System32, and run `rundll32 shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL tabletpc.cpl @1` to get the same dialog.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the horizontal direction that the menus in Visual Studio roll out  to by editing the registry as well (useful if the "Other" tab in Tablet PC Settings is not visible on your instance of Windows).

Open the registry (type `regedit` in the start menu and press Enter).

Navigate to this location:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows`

If you don't have an entry called `MenuDropAlignment`, right click and create a new StringValue (REG_SZ) called `MenuDropAlignment`.

Change the value of `MenuDropAlignment` to be whichever way you want the menus to open to.

0 = Menus open to right (this is the "normal" way that most people expect the menus to open)

1 = Menus open to left

Once you have finished making this change, close everything and restart your machine.