# Visual Studio menus aligned bad

Tags: visual-studio

Today I installed Visual Studio on my desktop PC and faced this:
[image]
Why menus are appearing this way (expanding to left)?

Same menu in my laptop expands this way:
[image]

Comment: What is "this way"? Do you have like a really low resolution, or have you resized the window to be so small as on your screenshot?

Comment: what's the "expected" menu?

Comment: @CodeCaster I captured and cropped screenshot using Screen snip.

Comment: @phuclv I edited post and added more details.

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58942483/259206